# How do I extract from the DataFrame based on three columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to shuffle and extract duplicated columns out of a Dataframe based on three columns.

I have tried to convert three columns into a dictionary and store their index and compare the Height. Row 4 is not unique dropped.

```
df['C']=df[["Color1","Color2","Color3"]].stack().apply(tuple)
df = df.duplicated(subset=["Color1","Color2","Color3"], keep=False)


     Height    Color1    Color2    Color3
0    Short      NaN       Blue      Red
1    High       Red       Blue      NaN
2    Medium     Blue       Red      NaN 
3    Short       NaN       NaN      Blue
4    Short       NaN       Red      Blue
5    High        NaN       NaN      NaN
```

The output of the code should be:

```
     Height    Color1    Color2    Color3
0    Short      NaN       Blue      Red
1    High       Red       Blue      NaN
2    Medium     Blue       Red      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset="Height")
```